# Override Decodable for a Particular Type

Tags: swift, decodable

Is there a way to override the Decodable implementation for a particular type, such that it gets used that type is part of a `Codable` struct?

Specifically, I have this struct:

```
struct Activity: Codable {
    let id: Int
    let name: String
<...>
    let distance: Measurement<UnitLength>
}
```

I'd like a way to provide an decoding initializer like this:

```
extension Measurement where UnitType == UnitLength {
    public init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        self = Measurement(value: try decoder.singleValueContainer().decode(Double.self), unit: UnitLength.meters)
    }
}
```

So that I can convert a `Double` value into a `Measurement<UnitLength>` on decoding, *without* having to provide a custom `init(from decoder: Decoder)` for each `struct` that has a `Measurement` in it.

That `init` compiles fine, but doesn't seem to be called from the standard `Codable` decoding process.

My workaround implementation is this init for the `Activity` struct:

```
init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
    let values = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)

<...>
    distance = Measurement(value: try values.decode(Double.self, forKey: .distance), unit: UnitLength.meters)
}
```

But I'd much rather implement it once on `Measurement` than for each type that might use it.

Comment: According to the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/measurement) `Measurement` does conform to `Decodable`

Comment: I suspect that your `Measurement` extension isn't working because you are attempting to override the `init(from:)` that is already provided by `Measurement` and its conformance to `Codable`. Extensions can't be used to override existing methods. It's undefined behavior.

Answer (score 2):

One solution that may meet your needs to is to define your own measurement struct that assumes a length measurement in meters.

```
struct MyMeasurement {
    let length: Measurement<UnitLength>
}

extension MyMeasurement: Codable {
    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.singleValueContainer()
        length = Measurement(value: try container.decode(Double.self), unit: UnitLength.meters)
    }

    func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
        var container = encoder.singleValueContainer()
        try container.encode(length.value)
    }
}
```

Then update your `Activity` struct to use `MyMeasurement`:

```
struct Activity: Codable {
    let id: Int
    let name: String
<...>
    let distance: MyMeasurement
}
```

Then you can decode normally:

```
let decoder = JSONDecoder()
do {
    let activity = try decoder.decode(Activity.self, from: someJSONData)
    print(activity.distance.length)
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

You probably want a better name for `MyMeasurement` that hints to it being a length in meters.

You can reuse `MyMeasurement` in any struct that has some length property in meters without the need to write a custom `init(from:)` for that struct.